# How to send HTTP response with multipart/related data in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, multipartform-data

I'm trying to send HTTP response with multipart/related data, which contain some random text data as first part and a binary data (certificate file in DER format) as the second part.

From Wireshark, it seems that the first part is correct but the second part (PKIX) is broken - WS shows a malformed packet.

I also tried to send data as Buffer but to no avail.

The code is something like this - am I missing something?

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {    

    var data = 'some data';
    var file = fs.readFileSync("cert.der");

    var responseData = '--abcd1234\r\n' +
                'Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8\r\n' + 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n' + 'Content-ID: <xxxx>\r\n\r\n' +
                data + '\r\n' +
                '--abcd1234\r\n' +
                'Content-type: application/pkix-cert\r\n' + 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n' + 'Content-ID: <yyyy>\r\n\r\n';

    res.writeHead(200, "OK", {'Content-Type': 'multipart/related; charset=utf-8; boundary="abcd1234"; type="text/xml"; start="<SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"'});
    res.write(responseData);
res.write(file);
res.end('\n\r--abcd1234--');
});

server.listen(8008);
```

Comment: You cannot send response with different content-type at a time

Comment: Got it working by sending parts in separate write-calls, see above.

Comment: @kiikale You have a working example? I need a nodejs server to serve images files with multipart/related. Thanks.